# Problem populating a list of children related to a queried sObject

Tags: apex, query, sobject, list

I have sObject1 called `sObject1__c` which is a parent(master-detail) to many sObjects2 each called `sObject2__c`.

So in my trigger I have an empty list of sObject2 related to sObject1:

`sObject1__c.sObject2s__r = ();`

So then I query for sObject2 and iterate over the returned list of results assigning its values to sObject1 like this:

`sObject1__c.sObject2s__r.add(sObject2__c);`

The code builds however the list `sObject1__c.sObject2s__r` remains empty. `System.debug(sObject2__c)` shows me that the object holds a value. Nonetheless that object doesn't get assigned to the corresponding list in sObject1.

**EDIT**

Here's some code as requested:

```
List<Interview_Result__c> listOfTestResults = [
            SELECT
                Test_Field__c
            FROM Test_Result__c
            WHERE Test_Process__c IN : mapOfTP.keySet()
        ];
for (Test_Process__c tprocess : mapOfTP.values()) {
    for (Test_Result__c tresult : listOfTestResults) {
        if (tprocess.Id == tresult.Test_Process__c) {
            tprocess.Test_Results__r.add(tresult);
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note that the `tprocess.Test_Results__r` is empty before I start adding to it.**

Comment: please post your complete code

Comment: @Himanshu - I did add some code. I hope that makes things more clear for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this construction is valid as child relationships can't be dynamically added to sobjects unless the original query included the child sObject

For example:

```
Account[] aList = [select id, name from Account limit 1];
for (Account a: aList) {
    a.contacts.add(new Contact (firstname = 'foo', lastname = 'bar', email= 'foo@bar.com', accountId = a.id));
    system.debug(logginglevel.INFO,a.name + ' has contacts: ' + a.contacts);
}
```

displays:

```
someAcctName has contacts: ()
```

You can populate via Apex parent relationships as in the following:

```
Contact c = new Contact(firstname = 'foo', lastname = 'bar', email ='foo@bar.com',
                                           account = new Account (name = 'someacctname'));
system.debug(logginglevel.INFO,'contact account name='+c.account.name);
```

Comment: So is there a work around my problem? How can I resolve my issue?

Comment: @arthlete just create an independent list of `Test_Result__c` and be sure to populate the lookup field to `Test_Process__c`; then you can do dml on the testResults list

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that the Test_Process__c is captured by the trigger having an empty lookup field as you referred to it.

Comment: @arthlete ah, since `Test_process__c` is the parent, in your trigger, simply requery `[select ..., (select id, ... from Trigger_results__r) from Trigger_process__c where id in :trigger.new.keyset()]` as the child relationships aren't implicitly in trigger scope. Or, I may be misunderstanding your issue altogether :-(